# Remove or move Marker (Mapbox Android)

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I'm using Mapbox SDK Android ('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.1@aar' and 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-services:1.1.0@aar').
I use offline map and put markers but remove and setposition dont' work.

I declare in global:

```
private MapboxMap mapboxMap2;
private MarkerViewOptions marker_inter;
```

Then in my OnMapReadyCallback(), I save the MapboxMap with:

```
 public void onMapReady(MapboxMap mapboxMap)
        {
            mapboxMap2 = mapboxMap;
```

so I'll be able to use it latter.

Also in OnMapReadyCallback I put the marker using:

```
                marker_inter = new MarkerViewOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(the_lagps_inter, the_logps_inter))
                        .title("Intervention")
                        .snippet("Desc inter")
                        .icon(iconeInter);
                markerView = mapboxMap.addMarker(marker_inter);
```

The marker is set correctly.
Then on onMapClick(@NonNull LatLng point) I retrieve the coord of the click (which are correct). But:

1) If I try to remove the marker using:

```
  mapboxMap2.removeMarker(marker_inter);
```

I get "*removeMarker (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.Marker) in MapboxMap cannot be applied to (com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.annotations.MarkerViewOptions)*"

2) If I try to set a new position using:

```
    marker_inter.setPosition(new LatLng(the_lagps_inter, the_logps_inter));
```

I get: "*Cannot resolve method 'setPosition(com.mapbox.maboxsdk.geometry.LatLng)*"

Note: I import com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.geometry.LatLng;

It seems removeMarker don't work with MarkerViewOptions and that setPosition is no more in geometry.LatLng??

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the marker using `MarkerView` not `MarkerViewOptions`. Change you code to this:

```
private MarkerView marker_inter;

...

marker_inter = mapboxMap.addMarker(new MarkerViewOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(the_lagps_inter, the_logps_inter))
    .title("Intervention")
    .snippet("Desc inter")
    .icon(iconeInter));
```

and then try removing the MarkerView and setting it's position.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I suggest  to update Mapbox example: at  https://www.mapbox.com/help/android-markers/ the "Add a marker" example code use "MarkerViewOptions marker" and then the "Remove a marker" explanation say "use mapboxMap.removeMarker(marker);" which is confusing. I'll post that on the Mapbox site. I'll post another question about map focus in a few min. ;)